# How do I delay an onClick image link so the .gif animation can finish before the page switches?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, onclick, delay, gif

I have a .gif animation that changes to a new .gif image source onClick that also links onClick to another page. I'm just trying to figure out how to delay the link so the second .gif animation finishes before it switches pages. How can I do this?

My current code (the link won't load when you run the snippet, but it works on the actual site) ;

```html
<img src="https://lowlifeclothing.co/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/Loop12.gif" onclick="location.href = 'https://lowlifeclothing.co/shop/" id="image1">
<script> document.getElementById("image1").addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.src = "https://lowlifeclothing.co/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/Loop12D.gif"; location.href = 'https://lowlifeclothing.co/shop/'

    
}); </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible example.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#image1").click(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", "https://lowlifeclothing.co/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/Loop12D.gif");
    var url = $(this).attr("data-click-href");
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.location.href = url;
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://lowlifeclothing.co/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/Loop12.gif" data-click-href="https://lowlifeclothing.co/shop/" id="image1">
```

This uses `setTimeout()` to wait 1000 ms or 1 second and then changes the URL. This give the GIF time to load and display the animation.

The primary issue is you had assigned two click events to the same element. The `onclick` would have priority and would redirect upon click.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Could I get some further help? I am a novice developer now trying to add this script into my site, I'm using Elementor block builder on Wordpress, how do I go about inserting this in? I have a custom HTML widget I've been writing the code in that has worked up until I tried to copy and paste your answer. It works when I run the snippet on StackOverflow, but not my site.

Comment: @hunnaharms I am not familiar with that WP Plugin. I would check the Support Docs for it or post a new question if you are still struggling.